# Leetcode Two Sum question. My code's time complexity is O(n^2). How can i make it simpler

Tags: time, time-complexity

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        i = 0
        while i <= (len(nums) - 1):   
            j = i + 1 
            for c, y  in enumerate(nums):
                if y == (target - nums[i]) and i != c:
                    return [i, c]
            i += 1
```

What should i replace the while loop with?

Answer (score 0):

Won't give you the exact code. But can give you an idea of the algorithm. 
Use a HashMap. Keep storing the difference of `target` and the current number as key and the position as value.

If you find the difference in `hashmap` then value of that entry and the current is your answer.

Algo:

```
for each number
    int diff = target - number
    if(map.contains(diff)) 
        return map.get(value), current index
    else 
        store the diff, index
```